# Где находится шаблон раздела <статьи> на Opencart

Tags: opencart

И как каждой из статей задать свой html. Я так понимаю, что шаблон выведет единым стилем любую из статей, а требуется для каждой из статей свой html и стиль.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартный шаблон статьи:
`/catalog/view/theme/**НАЗВАНИЕ_ТЕМЫ**/template/information/information.tpl`

Что бы у каждой статьи шаблон был индивидуальным нужно его сначала создать и  разместить на файловой системе, а потом подключить контроллере.

Как вариант, можно немного доработать контроллер и проверять наличие шаблона под каждую статью, используя id статьи в названии шаблона, а в случае если индивидуального шаблона нет, то подключать шаблон по умолчанию.

в /catalog/controller/information/information.php ~64 строка:

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('information/information', $data));
```

заменить на:

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('theme_default_directory') . '/template/information/information_' . $information_id . '.tpl')) {
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('information/information_'.$information_id, $data));
} else {
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('information/information', $data));
}
```

Затем разместите файл шаблона для конкретной статьи в директории **активной темы**: /catalog/view/theme/**НАЗВАНИЕ_ТЕМЫ**/template/information/information_**ID**.tpl

Вместо **ID** подставьте идентификатор статьи для которой подключаете индивидуальный шаблон.

Идентификатор статьи виден в URL во время ее редактирования через админ-панель.

Если URL выглядит вот так:

`/admin/index.php?route=catalog/information/edit&token=hB2g8zvfySYMT&information_id=4`

То идентификатор этой статьи будет 4, а файл с шаблоном будет называться `information_4.tpl`.